# Join two different columns from two different tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

i have two temporary table 
Table 1

```
 ID1         Name        ID2            Single
----------------------------------------------------
 1            ABC         1            100
 2            DEF         1            200
```

Table 2

```
 ID1         Name        ID2           Monthly
----------------------------------------------------
 3            PQR         2            500
 4            LMN         2            600
```

I want Output

```
 ID1         Name        ID2            Single   Monthly
--------------------------------------------------------
 1            ABC         1            100        NULL
 2            DEF         1            200        NULL
 3            PQR         2            NULL       500
 4            LMN         2            NULL       600
```

I used all Joins nothing working 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please look at the preview when writing a question. The initial formatting on this question made is *very* difficult to pick out the separate parts, and the tables weren't well formatted (they still aren't, but I'll try another edit shortly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN won't work for that case, you need to use [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) here:

```
SELECT ID1, NAME, ID2, Single, NULL FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID1, NAME, ID2, NULL, Monthly FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, for some mad reason, you really do need it as a `JOIN` rather than (as other's have pointed out) a `UNION ALL`:

```
create table #T1 (ID1 int,Name varchar(10),ID2 int,Single int)
insert into #T1 (ID1 ,        Name  ,      ID2    ,        Single)
select 1            ,'ABC',         1  ,          100 union all
select 2            ,'DEF',         1   ,         200

create table #T2 (ID1 int,Name varchar(10),ID2 int,Monthly int)
insert into #T2 (ID1 ,        Name  ,      ID2    ,        Monthly)
select 3            ,'PQR',         2   ,         500 union all
select 4            ,'LMN',         2   ,         600

select COALESCE(t1.ID1,t2.ID1) as ID1,COALESCE(t1.Name,t2.Name) as Name,
COALESCE(t1.ID2,T2.ID2) as ID2,t1.Single,t2.Monthly
from #T1 t1 full outer join #T2 t2 on 1=0
```

Gives the result you asked for

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `JOINS`, you need a [UNION (ALL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

> **UNION (Transact-SQL)**
>
> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT ID1, Name, ID2, Single, NULL as Monthly
FROM   Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID1, Name, ID2, Null, Monthly
FROM   Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM Single
UNION
SELECT * FROM Monthly
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't match the desired output, since it will only have the Single column and will include the monthly values in that column (and may eliminate values between the two tables when it shouldn't, since you've used `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following query...

Select
ID1,
Name,
ID2,
Single,
NULL AS 'Monthly"

from Table1

Union

Select
ID1,
Name,
ID2,
NULL AS 'Single',
Monthly

from Table2